# I have come across an error in SQL and cannot fix this foreign key error. See desc for more information

Tags: sql, database, foreign-keys, sql-insert, create-table

I have been receiving the error code 1452, i am trying to add keys to a table to keep data unqiue and useable in other tables. i have created the tables and can use the information already entered but i want to make the databases properly so i am trying to use the keys. please refer to the code below.

```
CREATE TABLE CUSTOMERS (
    CustID varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Client_Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Client_Address varchar(80) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (CustID)
);


CREATE TABLE ORDERS (
    Order_ID VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL,
    Client_NameID varchar(50) NOT NULL,
    Dates varchar(10) NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (Order_ID),
    FOREIGN KEY (Client_NameID) REFERENCES CUSTOMERS(CustID)
);

SELECT * FROM CUSTOMERS;
SELECT * FROM ORDERS;

DESCRIBE Orders; /*Used to display the Table*/

ALTER TABLE ORDERS ADD Dates VARCHAR(10); /*Used to add columns into the table*/

ALTER TABLE ORDERS DROP COLUMN Date; /*Used to remove column from the table*/

INSERT INTO CUSTOMERS (CustID, Client_Name, Client_Address) VALUES 
    ('168', 'Coventry Building Services', 'Units 2-4, Binley Industrial Estate, CV3 2WL'), /*Used to insert values into the columns*/
    ('527', 'Allied Construction LTD', '34, Lythalls La Industrial Estate, NG18 5AH'),
    ('169', 'Ricoh Builds Ltd', 'Unit 12, Stoneleigh Park, CV8 2UV'),
    ('32', 'British Embassy in Tehran', '198 Ferdowski Avenue Tehran 11316-91144 Iran');

INSERT INTO ORDERS (Order_ID, Client_NameID, Dates) VALUES 
    ('CON-2237', 'Coventry Building Services', '2014-12-14'),
    ('CON-3664', 'Allied Construction LTD', '2015-01-16'),
    ('CON-2356', 'Ricoh Builds Ltd', '2015-02-12'),
    ('CON-1234', 'British Embassy in Tehran', '2015-04-16');


DELETE FROM ORDERS WHERE Client_Name='Coventry Building Services'; /*Used to delete specific 
data from the specific row and column wherever applicable*/

DROP TABLE CUSTOMERS;
DROP TABLE ORDERS;
```

Below are the tables im trying to work with, all of them will pretty much have a key that links them together if necessary

[The CustomerS Table which only includes a Primary Key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iRcgl.png)

[The Orders Table which includes a Primary and Foreign key](https://i.stack.imgur.com/F4LTw.png)

Comment: Please add the tag for your RDBMS to your Question. "error code 1452" doesn't mean much unless one know which database you mean. You can remove the "database" tag.

Comment: Please in code questions give a [mre]--cut & paste & runnable code, including smallest representative example input as code; desired & actual output (including verbatim error messages); tags & versions; clear specification & explanation. Give the least code you can that is code that you show is OK extended by code that you show is not OK. (Debugging fundamental.) For SQL that includes DBMS & DDL (including constraints & indexes) & input as code formatted as a table. [ask] Pause work on the overall goal, chop code to the 1st expression not giving what you expect & say what you expect & why.

Comment: Please before considering posting read your textbook and/or manual & google any error message or many clear, concise & precise phrasings of your question/problem/goal, with & without your particular strings/names & site:stackoverflow.com & tags; read many answers. If you post a question, use one phrasing as title. Reflect your research. See [ask] & the voting arrow mouseover texts. PS Once you give input data as tablular initialization code you don't need images. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `insert`s into table `orders. Your foreign key on` Client_NameID`references`CUSTOMERS(CustID)`, but you are giving the CUSTOMERS(Client_Name)` instead.

You probably want:

```
INSERT INTO ORDERS (Order_ID, Client_NameID, Dates) VALUES
    ('CON-2237', 'CON-2237', '2014-12-14');
    ('CON-3664', 'CON-3664', '2015-01-16');
    ('CON-2356', 'CON-2356', '2015-02-12');
    ('CON-1234', 'CON-1234', '2015-04-16');
```

Notes:

- You can perform all `insert`s in a single query by passing several tuples of values, as shown above
- Don't store dates as strings; instead, use the `date` datatype, which exists for that purpose. I changed the query so it uses proper date literals, which would fit in a `date` column
- it is unclear why you want to use the same value for the primary key of customers and orders - to me, this makes things harder to follow. I would recommend just using auto-incremented primary keys

Comment: Ok, i'll give this a try and see how it goes

Comment: Have changed the values to the data i wish to use. Running this code still gives me the same error (Error 1452)